# How to write php inside return html?

Tags: php

I'm a real newbie to php and I just cant figure this out!
I want different images to appear depending on what rating value is returned from the database.How do I do that?!
This is the code:

```
    return '
        <div class="comment">
            <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
            <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
            <div class="rating">'.$d['rating'].'</div>
            <p>'.$d['body'].'</p>
        </div>
    ';
```

So if the value is 5 I want the image 5stars.png to show up.
I thought maybe you could write something like:

```
<img src="img/<?php echo $row['rating']; ?>stars.png">
```

But that won't work inside the return statement. What do I have to write to be able to write php inside the ? Is it even possible?

Comment: can you show me how you mean? lol

Answer (score 3):

You would do it like this:

```
return '
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="name">'.$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close.'</div>
        <div class="date" title="Added at '.date('H:i \o\n d M Y',$d['dt']).'">'.date('d M Y',$d['dt']).'</div>
        <div class="rating">'.$d['rating'].'</div>
        <p><img src="img/' . $d['rating'] . 'stars.png"></p>
    </div>
';
```

You can't use `echo` inside a string, as you have noticed. Instead, you use the `.` operator to concatenate strings.

Please note: this is a pretty basic question and not really suited for this site. I would recommend that you find a good tutorial on PHP basics and start there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've searched for the answer but haven't find it. This seemed so complicated so I thought my best shot at getting this right was to ask here.

When I try that code, it wont read the rating value at all and just try to show "stars.png".

Comment: @Jenetic Well, you refer to `$row` in your question, but your `return` value originally had `$d`. You haven't posted enough info to make clear what you need, but I suspect you need to change `$row['rating']` to `$d['rating']`.